# Using margin-top within a div applies margin to header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply a margin to  text within a `div`, to have text centered horizontally and vertically. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, as I'm very new to HTML and programming in general.

```html
<!-- begin header -->
<header style="background-color:#8b0000" style="height:50px;">
<!-- frankenstien-ish bootstrap grid within a bootstrap grid -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
     <!-- this div is a placeholder div and has no content -->
</div>
<!-- this div contains all of the navigation buttons in their own bootstrap 
grid -->
<div class="col-md-6">
  <p style="text-align:center;margin">Test Text</p>
<!-- I know the margin has no value right now. Read question -->
</div>
</div>
</header>
<!-- end header -->
```

When I try to apply a margin to the `<p>` element, the margin makes the header larger and doesn't affect the `<p>` element's margin. How can I center an element vertically and horizontally? (The `<p>` is a test. It will be replaced with a button)

Comment: Try using `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: It still increases the size of the header without affecting the p element.

Comment: I can't tell what it is you're trying to do. Can you draw a picture of what you're expecting to see?

Comment: So I have a header on top, with a background color. The header is  50px high. I'm going to have 2 buttons within the header. I want the buttons to be centered vertically and horizontally, without changing the height of the header. I have 2 `div` elements in a bootstrap grid, and these buttons will be in their own grid within one of the `div` elements, in order for the buttons to be centered on 50% of the header, if that makes sense. Split the header into 2 vertical sections, and the buttons are centered within one of the sections.

Comment: You should update your post with the code per this comment with what you're actually using and what the end goal is.

Comment: Everything relevant is updated. No CSS classes are being used for this area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments in your code it's clear that you are trying to create some navigation buttons. I'm not sure about bootstrap but in general I prefer using list items when I build navigation buttons. The reason is its really easy to control, edit and understand the structure.

Coming to your question, flex box are very comfortable to center align contents inside another, but I will not prefer that in this use case instead go with an, `<li>`or   `<div>` tag - > add the name inside and then set the gaps using padding.

```
<ul class="navbtn">
      <li>button 1 </li>
      <li>button 2 </li>
      <li>button 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Now the CSS will be

```
.navbtn li {
padding : 10px 5px;
}
```

Play with the values as per your comfort
This will center align the text inside the box.

Using list item will be more conformable than anything else when it comes to adding navigation buttons.

Comment: How can I use this to make the buttons side by side?